# How do I reset my wallet (bitcoin qt)

Tags: bitcoin-core

I lost my wallet pass, but thankfully didn't have any money there. How do I reset this thing and get a new fresh wallet with a new password?

Comment: I know people always recommend encrypting the wallet, but IMO loss is a much more serious problem than theft. If you do encrypt make sure the password is stored properly, preferably both in your memory and in multiple physical locations.

Comment: If you had funds in there, here's an interesting thread  to read.  A person encrypted the wallet but made a typo when entering the pass phrase and then the same typo during the second verification as well.

Fortunately, some cracking efforts were able to find the variation off the expected pass phrase and the coins were recovered.  https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=85495.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Bitcoin's [Application Data directory](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory) (in Windows 7 it's UserFolder\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin) and delete the wallet.dat file.

Comment: How would you delete wallet.dat on a mac?

Comment: @sean: I added a link to a Bitcoin wiki page detailing the location of the data directory on various OSes; according to it, on a Mac it is ~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/.